# How to make multiple directory in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

How can you generate a url in asp.net mvc that contains more than the default controller, action, id. And also how are hyphens put in a controller?

Default url in asp.net mvc is:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

How is a url like this made:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/28990934/two-models-in-same-view-in-asp-net-mvc
or
site.com/some-thing/otherthings/more-things/the-things.html
```

Comment: Add additional parameters to your route `{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}`

Comment: @stephenMuecke How would I use that? I know that the id is usually used in a query string ex. `site.com/something/other?id=stuff` . Is there another way to use it?

Comment: @User456789 ID is not normally in a query string in an MVC application, it's normally specified as part of the URL pattern. There's normally no query string at all (though you are still free to use it).

Comment: @User456789, Your question is far too broad. You need to do some research on routing in MVC and narrow down your question to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can create customized URLs however you like, as long you have a controller, an action and n parameters for example http://yourdomain.com/bla/bla/mystuff/< controller>/< action>/< param1>/< param2>/< param3>, it depends on what you want. Maybe this would help you  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC.